# I tried to build a vue project with Parcel and now fails……or said, I got some error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, parcel

I just tried to build a vue project and set the directory structure to be similar to the vue-cli generated project. And I got some error after just used vue-router function.
The error is:

[image]

Following is my directory structure :

```
- Parcel
  - src
    - components
      - Index.vue
    - router
      - index.js
    - App.vue
    - main.js
  - node_modules
  - index.html
  - package.json
```

In order to see more clearly, I wrote out part of the source code demo:

**index.html**

```
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="./src/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

**src/main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import router from './router/index.js'
import App from './App.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    router,
    template: '<App/>',
    components: { App }
})
```

**src/App.vue**

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>App Page</h1>
        <router-view></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

**router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Index from '../components/Index.vue'

Vue.use(Router);
export default new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            component: Index
        }
    ]
})
```

Comment: Can you also show the contents of components/Index.vue?

Comment: Ok,but I think it’s no effect...

Comment: `<template><div id="index"> <p>Index Page</p></div></template>`

Comment: Code goes in your question, **not in the comments**

Comment: @Phil Can you elaborate on it, bro?

Comment: Sure. You posted some code into a comment (bad). You should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47766006/edit) and put the code in there (good)

Comment: Perhaps try adding `<script>` blocks to your components. Just something like `<script>export default {}</script>`. Could be the loader is turning your template-only components into strings

Comment: @Phil OK……I mistakenly think that you said I have a problem with my code

Comment: I'm wondering whether it does not support `import .vue `

Answer (score 1):

To make single file components work, you must install the following:

```
npm install @vue/component-compiler-utils vue-template-compiler --save-dev
npm install vue-hot-reload-api --save
```

The plugin https://github.com/BoltDoggy/parcel-plugin-vue is not recommended since parcel-bundler/parcel @1.7.0 supports Vue now.

I created a simple boilerplate for Vue and Parcel if you're interested. https://github.com/sorxrob/vue-parcel

Answer (score 0):

The parcel bundler does not support the extention `.vue` by default. You need first to use the [parcel-plugin-vue](https://github.com/lc60005457/parcel-plugin-vue).